# Lazy transform in C++

Tags: c++, python, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I have the following Python snippet that I would like to reproduce using C++:

```
from itertools import count, imap

source = count(1)
pipe1 = imap(lambda x: 2 * x, source)
pipe2 = imap(lambda x: x + 1, pipe1)
sink = imap(lambda x: 3 * x, pipe2)
for i in sink:
    print i
```

I've heard of [Boost Phoenix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html), but I couldn't find an example of a lazy `transform` behaving in the same way as Python's `imap`.

Edit: to clarify my question, the idea is not only to apply functions in sequence using a `for`, but rather to be able to use algorithms like `std::transform` on infinite generators. The way the functions are composed (in a more functional language like dialect) is also important, as the next step is function composition.

Update: thanks bradgonesurfing, David Brown, and Xeo for the amazing answers! I chose Xeo's because it's the most concise and it gets me right where I wanted to be, but David's was very important into getting the concepts through. Also, bradgonesurfing's tipped Boost::Range :).

Comment: I got this far and realised it wasn't going to happen easily: Python... reproduce in C++... itertools.

Comment: Nice; this can certainly be done in C++, though it won't be quite as short.

Comment: Small comment on your original code - it would be easier read, in my opinion, with [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) rather than `imap`, since you're only taking values from one iterator at a time. `pipe1 = (2*x for x in source)`.

Comment: Moreover, your code would be better (simpler, faster, etc) as a single expression, rather than lots of nested iterators. `sink = (3 * (2*x + 1) for x in count(1))`

Comment: Yes, generator expressions would be simpler to read, @poorsod (and more 'Pythonic'). This is just a simple example to illustrate what I want to accomplish in C++. Please note that the resulting 'pipeline' would be (way) more complex :).

Comment: Yes, I know it won't be as short, @KerrekSB. I already accomplished writing an infinite number generator (that can be generalized for any infinite generator) - now I need to be able to use it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Employing [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/):

```
int main(){
  auto map = boost::adaptors::transformed; // shorten the name
  auto sink = generate(1) | map([](int x){ return 2*x; })
                          | map([](int x){ return x+1; })
                          | map([](int x){ return 3*x; });
  for(auto i : sink)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

[Live example including the `generate` function.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/841508d3b54bed4181d4e9fb6058200f)

Comment: That's beautiful, Xeo! And short! What are you using to compile the example, though? I'm getting errors with gcc 4.6.1 and boost 1.51 (using `-std=c++0x`).

Comment: I replaced `using generate_range = boost::iterator_range<generate_iterator>;` with `typedef boost::iterator_range<generate_iterator>;` and it works :). What kind of dialect is the first one, Xeo?

Comment: @bruno: C++11 dialect. ;) GCC 4.6 didn't implement using aliases, it seems. And I used GCC 4.7.2, as can be seen in the example link.

Comment: This is very cool with one small failing. Its pretty hard to figure out the type of sink. Thus if you want to return it from a function you need to declare the type. I came across a polymorphic range/iterator library once that erases the complex type. There was a small performance hit.

Comment: @brad: If you're using normal functors, the trailing-return-type works wonders here. Sadly, lambdas aren't allowed inside of `decltype`, so it's not applicable here. What you can use, though, is [`boost::any_range`](http://www.boost.org/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html).

Comment: Yes boost::any_range is exactly what i was talking about. It wasn't in the lib last time i used boost and had to roll my own. Good to know.

Comment: With Boost.Lambda it becomes even prettier:" | map( x * 2 ) | map( x + 1 ) ". http://liveworkspace.org/code/d66be4d7b00c78af809780414fb09f08

Answer (score 5):

I think the most idiomatic way to do this in C++ is with iterators. Here is a basic iterator class that takes an iterator and applies a function to its result:

```
template<class Iterator, class Function>
class LazyIterMap
{
private:
    Iterator i;
    Function f;
public:
    LazyIterMap(Iterator i, Function f) : i(i), f(f) {}
    decltype(f(*i)) operator* () { return f(*i); }
    void operator++ () { ++i; }
};

template<class Iterator, class Function>
LazyIterMap<Iterator, Function> makeLazyIterMap(Iterator i, Function f)
{
    return LazyIterMap<Iterator, Function>(i, f);
}
```

This is just a basic example and is still incomplete as it has no way to check if you've reached the end of the iterable sequence.

Here's a recreation of your example python code (also defining a simple infinite counter class).

```
#include <iostream>

class Counter
{
public:
    Counter (int start) : value(start) {}
    int operator* () { return value; }
    void operator++ () { ++value; }
private:
    int value;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Counter source(0);
    auto pipe1 = makeLazyIterMap(source, [](int n) { return 2 * n; });
    auto pipe2 = makeLazyIterMap(pipe1, [](int n) { return n + 1; });
    auto sink = makeLazyIterMap(pipe2, [](int n) { return 3 * n; });
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i, ++sink)
    {
        std::cout << *sink << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Apart from the class definitions (which are just reproducing what the python library functions do), the code is about as long as the python version.

Comment: Apart from your `exapmle` typo, this looks very interesting (and simple). I wonder if a (possibly Boost) library exists that allow me to do this (and possibly much more :)). I'm looking into Boost::Rangex right nowm, as bradgonesurfing suggested.

Comment: @brunonery boost's [transform iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) is probably worth looking into.

Comment: I looked into `transform iterators` and they are very promising. However, the fact that you have to specify the input iterator type confuses me. How would you specify a `transform_iterator` that works on another `transform_iterator`? Like rewriting this example using `transform_iterator` :)

Comment: @brunonery look at the [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html#example) on the boost page, it very similar to this. In my code you can almost just replace `makeLazyIterMap` with `boost::make_transform_iterator`. However my counter class isn't compatable with boosts standard iterators it seems. If you replace it with one of boosts ranges it should work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the boost::rangex library is what you are looking for. It should work nicely with the new c++lambda syntax.

Comment: Can one have infinite ranges with boost::rangex?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html

Comment: Yes I think you can as they are based on iterators. A range just has a begin and an end iterator. No reason your end cannot be infinity for whatever type you are generating

Comment: I'm drooling right now, bradgonesurfing. I'll take a deeper look at this. The syntax with pipes look amazing :)

Comment: The helper you want is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html

Comment: It specifically mentions lazy generators

Comment: And if you want to look at something real nice/scary http://pfultz2.github.com/Linq/

Answer (score 1):

```
int pipe1(int val) {
    return 2*val;
}

int pipe2(int val) {
    return val+1;
}

int sink(int val) {
    return val*3;
}

for(int i=0; i < SOME_MAX; ++i)
{
    cout << sink(pipe2(pipe1(i))) << endl;
}
```

I know, it's not quite what you were expecting, but it certainly evaluates at the time you want it to, although not with an iterator iterface. A very related article is this:

[Component programming in D](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/component-programming-in-d/240008321)

Edit 6/Nov/12:

An alternative, still sticking to bare C++, is to use function pointers and construct your own piping for the above functions (vector of function pointers from SO q: [How can I store function pointer in vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758121/how-can-i-store-function-pointer-in-vector)):

```
typedef std::vector<int (*)(int)> funcVec;
int runPipe(funcVec funcs, int sinkVal) {
    int running = sinkVal;
    for(funcVec::iterator it = funcs.begin(); it != funcs.end(); ++it) {
        running = (*(*it))(running); // not sure of the braces and asterisks here
    }
    return running;
}
```

This is intended to run through all the functions in a vector of such and return the resulting value. Then you can:

```
funcVec funcs;
funcs.pushback(&pipe1);
funcs.pushback(&pipe2);
funcs.pushback(&sink);

for(int i=0; i < SOME_MAX; ++i)
{
    cout << runPipe(funcs, i) << endl;
}
```

Of course you could also construct a wrapper for that via a struct (I would use a closure if C++ did them...):

```
struct pipeWork {
     funcVec funcs;
     int run(int i);
};

int pipeWork::run(int i) {
    //... guts as runPipe, or keep it separate and call:
    return runPipe(funcs, i);
}

// later...
pipeWork kitchen;
kitchen.funcs = someFuncs;
int (*foo) = &kitchen.run();

cout << foo(5) << endl;
```

Or something like that. Caveat: No idea what this will do if the pointers are passed between threads.

Extra caveat: If you want to do this with varying function interfaces, you will end up having to have a load of `void *(void *)(void *)` functions so that they can take whatever and emit whatever, or lots of templating to fix the kind of pipe you have. I suppose ideally you'd construct different kinds of pipe for different interfaces between functions, so that `a | b | c` works even when they are passing different types between them. But I'm going to guess that that's largely what the Boost stuff is doing.

Comment: Specially because I cannot use an infinite generator there.

Comment: @Vlad: it is lazy in the sense that you call the functions when you are about to push the value out, rather than generating lists of intermediate values; the memory requirement is just one value at a time. However, it is not lazy in the sense that evaluation can be separated from the declaration.

Comment: That's interesting, PhilH - but D is not an option, unfortunately. Is there something as components for C++?

Comment: @brunonery: that's what I've been hoping for for some time.

Comment: @brunonery: the edit should permit infinite generators, passing the compound function around etc.

Answer (score -4):

Depending on the simplicity of the functions :

```
#define pipe1(x) 2*x
#define pipe2(x) pipe1(x)+1

#define sink(x) pipe2(x)*3

int j = 1
while( ++j > 0 )
{
    std::cout << sink(j) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This looks very close to PhilH answer above, but 1. you don't even call the pipeline anywhere and 2. ++j, when j=1, will always be >0.

Comment: 1. OK typo error, you shoud read cout << sink(j) << end; 2. I know it is an infinite loop, it was just to recreate the count(1) which don't end neither. The solution is close to PhilH's one, but I think preprocessor directives closer to Python lambda expression than function IMHO