# Composing adaptors in Boost::range

Tags: c++, boost, functional-programming, boost-range

I started playing with Boost::Range in order to have a [pipeline of lazy transforms in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144280/lazy-transform-in-c). My problem now is how to split a pipeline in smaller parts. Suppose I have:

```
int main(){
  auto map = boost::adaptors::transformed; // shorten the name
  auto sink = generate(1) | map([](int x){ return 2*x; })
                          | map([](int x){ return x+1; })
                          | map([](int x){ return 3*x; });
  for(auto i : sink)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

And I want to replace the first two maps with a `magic_transform`, i.e.:

```
int main(){
  auto map = boost::adaptors::transformed; // shorten the name
  auto sink = generate(1) | magic_transform()
                          | map([](int x){ return 3*x; });
  for(auto i : sink)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

How would one write `magic_transform`? I looked up [Boost::Range's documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/extending/method_3.html), but I can't get a good grasp of it.

**Addendum**: I'm looking to write a class like this:

```
class magic_transform {
    ... run_pipeline(... input) {
        return input | map([](int x){ return 2*x; })
                     | map([](int x){ return x+1; });
};
```

Comment: What is the return type of `generate`? I am worried that your `sink` contains a reference to a temporary that expires at the semicolon.

Comment: `generate`'s return type is `boost::iterator_range`, please check http://liveworkspace.org/code/841508d3b54bed4181d4e9fb6058200f for details.

Comment: Magic transform does not get an input parameter.  You wrote it as a nullary function.

Comment: OK, it would be more a class than a function. See above.

Comment: Your needs are still vague.  Is it the pipe syntax you want?  A transform around chained lamdas gives the functionality and external use of |.  Do you actually want | within your magic_transform, and if so why?

Comment: Yes, I want | within my magic_transform - I'm designing a program that consists mostly of a pipeline, and the pipeline can get complex. I want to be able to break it into smaller pipes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most difficult problem is figuring out the return type in the code. `decltype` and lambdas do not mix well ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846540/c11-lambda-in-decltype)), so we have to think of an alternative way:

```
auto map = boost::adaptors::transformed;

namespace magic_transform
{
   std::function<int(int)> f1 = [](int x){ return 2*x; };
   std::function<int(int)> f2 = [](int x){ return x+1; };
   template <typename Range>
   auto run_pipeline(Range input) -> decltype(input | map(f1) | map(f1))
   {
        return input | map(f1) | map(f2);
   }
}

...
auto sink = magic_transform::run_pipeline(generate(1))
                          | map([](int x){ return 3*x; });
```

The simple solution is stick the lambdas into `std::function` so we can use `decltype` to deduce the return type. I used  namespace `magic_transform` in the example, but you could adapt this code into a class if you would like also. [Here is a link](http://liveworkspace.org/code/66609a2ebe8dd2decad0408b678eb82b) adapting your code to the above.

Also, using `std::function` might be overkill here. Instead you could just declare two normal functions instead ([example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/6b6480394ec93927d9a470da5f37bcd2)).

I was also experimenting with `boost::any_range`, there seems to be some incompatibilities with C+11 lambdas, etc. The closest I could get was the following ([example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/b33f529f1a0f8038bfccb3d6f035fca9)):

```
auto map = boost::adaptors::transformed;
using range = boost::any_range<
               const int,
               boost::forward_traversal_tag,
               const int&,
               std::ptrdiff_t
               >;

namespace magic_transform
{
    template <typename Range>
    range run_pipeline(Range r)
    {
        return r | map(std::function<int(int)>([](int x){ return 2*x; }))
             | map(std::function<int(int)>([](int x){ return x+1; }));
    }
}

int main(){
  auto sink = magic_transform::run_pipeline(boost::irange(0, 10))
                          | map([](int x){ return 3*x; });
  for(auto i : sink)
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Before asking here, I tried `decltype` and found it too verbose for this application (you end up writing the pipeline twice). The `any_range`, OTOH, allows you to only specify input and output, correct?

Comment: Now I see, `any_range` specifies the output (value and reference). Interesting.

Comment: Also, you can use `any_range` for the parameter too. E.g.: `range run_pipeline(range r)` defines a pipeline that acts on a range of ints and returns a range of ints.

Comment: @brunonery: Yes, I couldn't get `any_range` to work with your `generate(1)` example though.

Comment: @brunonery: I found out you need to change the iterator tag to `std::forward_iterator_tag`, [here is a working example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/97445258abe19613c766a921e1adbab1).

Answer (score 1):

I think will work:

```
auto magic_transform()->decltype(boost::adaptors::transformed(std::function<int(int)>())
{
    std::function<int(int)> retval = [](int x){ return [](int x){ return x+1; }(2*x);
    return boost::adaptors::transformed(retval);
}
```

but it probably isn't what you are looking for.  :)  (Jokes in the above code: chained lambdas for 2*x+1, use of decltype on basically the implementation to find the return type),

Looking at the source code for `http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp`, the type that `magic_transform` wants to return is `boost::range_detail::transform_holder<T>`, where T is the type of the function.

When you do it on the stack with lambdas, `T` ends up being some very narrow type.  If you want to pass around abstract transformations without exposing all of the details, using `std::function<outtype(intype)>` may be reasonable (there will be a small run-time overhead).

Hope that works.

Comment: Yes, chaining the lambdas wasn't what I was looking for :), please check my update. I could actually use `auto` and `decltype`, but I wanted something more generic.

Comment: So you want some way to pipe (well combine in order) transforms together and have the result be a transform?

Comment: Not only transforms, but eventually filters and other range adaptors.

Comment: Range adaptor's result type is documentated. for example, `transformed` returns boost::transformed_range<Range> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/transformed.html